# How to fully remove a mongoDB replicaset?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB cluster with 4 different replica set.
Lately 2 machines crashed in an unrecoverable way, the data are fully gone on this.
Sadly 1 replica set was installed on those 2 hosts.

The issue I'm facing is that the configuration still indicate that some data are on this replica set hosts and when client application try to read from those collection that happen to have chunks on those machine it returns this error:

> Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for
> set replicaSetShardServer4

Which make sens since those 2 server are gone.

So I wanted to find a way to remove those server from the config but every procedure i'm looking for mention to connect on the primary node of the replica set and remove shards which I can't do since then again those host are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the config file and comment lines

```
replication:
   replSetName: ...
```

Restart the Mongo service. Connect to the node and drop the `local` database.

```
db.getSiblingDB('local').dropDatabase()
```

By this you revert the ReplicaSet back to a Stand-alone MongoDB. After this you con configure the ReplicaSet again, see: [Convert a Standalone mongod to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

Have also a look at [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/), the procedure is the same as needed in your case - apart from the first step, "Obtain backup MongoDB Database files" - this step is not needed, of course.